# How can I view the minimal required arguments of a Wolfram Language function?

Tags: functions, input, arguments

This question might be a bit of an overstretch, or really obvious, but I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

Is there a way to automatically view the minimum required arguments for a WL function? For example, `Sin` only requires 1 argument, while `Replace` requires both an expression and the list of rules. Is there a way that, for example, I can input `Sin` into a function, and get back something like `{Real}`, or enter `Replace`, and get back `{Expression, Rules}`?

I hope this makes sense - I would like to be able to automate input to any function in Mathematica, by being given the required arguments.

Thanks!

Comment: `Is there a way to automatically view the minimum` You might be able to parse it out from the output of `Information[functionName]`, It will list all the different signatures of the function there, one per line.

Comment: That's a good idea, however, when I try val = Information[Replace], and then view the results with ?val, it returns that val = Null

Comment: @Jmeeks29ig `Information` has _side effects_ and doesn't _return_ anything. Fortunately we can scrape the side effects with `Block[{CellPrint = Sow},
 Reap[Information[Replace]][[-1, 1]]]`. However `Replace::usage` would be an easier way to see the information your after.

Comment: Great, thanks! I hadn't known that was possible

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`SyntaxInformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html):

```
SyntaxInformation /@ {Sin, Replace} // Column
```

[image]

Comment: It works - thanks!!!

Comment: @Jmeeks29ig, you are most welcome.